# Could/should/would fans be running while the system is asleep

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, sleep-wake

Could/should/would fans be running while the system is asleep (on a MacBook Pro 16 w/Catalina 10.15.4)?

I did find the Remote Login service enabled, but am not certain if this would prevent sleeping? All other services listed are disabled.

[image]

I also made sure that the settings for Power Nap were disabled in the Energy Saver preferences (and all other suggestions here: [If your Mac won’t go to or stay in sleep](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-your-mac-wont-go-to-or-stay-in-sleep-mchlp2995/mac)):

**Note:** I couldn't find the “Computer sleep” slider.

[image]
[image]

Bluetooth is also disabled, and Bluetooth devices are prevented from waking the system:

[image]

This is a new machine with only Xcode and Visual Studio installed (as well as Boom3D from the App Store, though the symptoms existed before it's installation).

---

I did find a potentially useful post in the comments here [macOS Catalina is a Disruptive POS — No System Sleep, Displays Won’t Sync](https://macperformanceguide.com/blog/2020/20200301_2208-macOS-Catalina-AppleCoreRot-system-sleep.html) for debugging power states, though would like to rule out any "usual suspects" first:

> Aln K writes:
>
> These tips require Terminal and understanding output redirection to a
>   file.
>
> I had a hard time with Apple on this even escalating to SVP. What you
>   should do is:
>
> 1. in Terminal run pmset -g everything >pmset-everything-before.txt
> 2. in Terminal run pmset -g pslog
> 3. put Mac to sleep (e.g. using Apple menu, key shortcut, lid closed etc., !!! beware the method of doing this is relevant !!!)
> 4. when Mac wakes up examine output
> 5. do 1) again as pmset -g everything >pmset-everything-after.txt
>
> (Note: Mac's behavior is power source dependent - battery or AC.)
>
> You will find a lot of info in the 'everything' file (everything just
>   invokes all commands in series), especially current settings for each
>   power source and /var/log/powermanagement entries. These entries will
>   tell you all processes affecting power management (best is to read the
>   manual with 'man pmset' or place cursor near the word and use the
>   'open man' item in Help menu).
>
> For example, if you put your Mac to sleep over night while running "-g
>   live" you can see what happened all night long. Running 'pmset -g log'
>   will reveal all events including wake-ups for all the nightly tasks
>   (you will better route the output to a file.)
>
> For example you can find out what I have found. There was a bug I
>   reported a while back with 'autopoweroffdelay' (put in hibernation
>   after specified time, defaults to 28800) which is set to obey EU
>   directive. I don't know if this is still the case but whatever you
>   entered for this parameter, its internal variables would truncate it
>   to 3 hours max. (= waking up from hibernation every 3 hours -
>   interesting coincidence: for boundary checks, masking this parameter
>   with 3FFF yields max. 3 integer.)

Comment: Just a friendly piece of feedback - while I do appreciate the size and spacing of your images (many folks could take lessons from you!), in this case you could have just used a few sentences.  Also, including an entire post from someone else increases the bloat.  Shorter, easier to read posts tend to attract more views and increases your chances of getting a quality answer.  But +1 for an excellent question, nonetheless!

Comment: I thought the spacing looked off, probably need to crop (not used to "Preview"). I find succinctness to be an art of balance depending on the question. I was explicit here to head off any question-comments pertaining to any already attempted troubleshooting steps.